# systemd: Limit concurrent start at boot for a custom service

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel7

We have defined a "myapp@.service" file which handles our application server starts.
On some servers there are a lot of application servers and we hit issues where one or two servers won't start.

This is a RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 server.

Is there a way to limit the number of concurrent / simultaneous processes for this one service?

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Appserver Instance %i
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/custom/server start %i
ExecStop=/custom/server stop %i
PIDFile=/custom/servers/.pid/%i.pid
User=%i
SuccessExitStatus=1
TimeoutStartSec=600
TimeoutStopSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Target is that all servers should start, but at boot time I don't want *all* of them to start at the same time. They should all be able to *run* at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the ordering, you can use an `ExecStartPre` with a small variable sleep. `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'sleep $(( RANDOM % 5 ))'` should make batch them into five buckets, each delayed by a second.  If you need to control the order, you can use a `.path` unit per instance and a limiter that touches the paths in the order you want.

Comment: I see how one can at least prevent absolute concurrency - which would help - with the sleep sollution. Could you elaborate on the .path sollution?